# Помогите с пунктуацией 1

Tags: пунктуация

В связи с отказами со стороны уполномоченных представителей ОМС в согласовании комиссионных актов приемки МКД, прошу Вас организовать серию совещаний с участием представителей Фонда капитального ремонта МКД и уполномоченных представителей, следующих ОМС:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вторая запятая действительно не нужна.

Насчет директора. Он, как я понимаю, предлагает обособлять конструкцию "со стороны уполномоченных представителей ОМС" - зачем, совершенно непонятно. Это даже не интонационное обособление, это просто блажь какая-то, обособлять обычный член предложения "со стороны".

А директору скажите, что правила пишутся на те случаи, когда знак ставится, а не когда он не нужен. Так что *задача обоснования знака ложится на того, кто его предлагает поставить*.

Но речь-то прежде всего не о запятой после "приемки МКД", там она может иметь место (хотя не обязательна), а о запятой после слов "уполномоченных представителей". Она там вообще ничем не мотивирована в принципе, просто "от балды" поставлена - и неудачно. Кстати, ваше непонимание - следствие безобразной стилистики. Три раза "представителей" на две с половиной строчки это перебор.
(+)
А, кажется я понял. Директор, видимо спутал с шаблоном "в лице ...(,) с одной стороны, и ...(,) с другой стороны" - тут иногда предлагают обособлять "для наглядности". Но мало того, что эта рекомендация весьма спорная сама по себе, так она ещё и не имеет ничего общего с нашим случаем.

Answer (score 1):

Последняя запятая (после "представителей") не нужна.

Comment: директор утверждает, что запятые нужны после слов - с отказами и ОМС. Говорит докажи мне правилами обратное

Comment: А вы ему в ответ: доказывать нужно не ненужность запятых, а их необходимость. Это как презумпция невиновности. И пусть доказывает. А вы: просто нет причин для постановки, вот и всё. ))